# Random generate image from json and display in div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to fetch these 12 images (or more) from a JSON file randomly and display them inside 6 divs on each refresh. I am able to get this solution through the below method. But I need solution to get same output by reading from a JSON file.

Thanks for your valuable comments.

**JS:**

```
$('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').each(function() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1),
    img = $(this);
  img.attr('src', '/img/instant_rewards/prize' + num + '.jpg');
  img.attr('data-block', num);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ir_game_container">
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSON:**

```
{
 "imageList": [
  {
    "image_1": "/img/prize1.jpg",
    "image_2": "/img/prize2.jpg",
    "image_3": "/img/prize3.jpg",
    "image_4": "/img/prize4.jpg",
    "image_5": "/img/default.jpg",
    "image_6": "/img/default.jpg",
    "image_7": "/img/default.jpg",
    "image_8": "/img/default.jpg",
    "image_9": "/img/default.jpg",
    "image_10": "/img/default.jpg",
    "image_11": "/img/default.jpg",
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to parse your JSON into an array. There are a few ways to do this, the easiest way would probably be using ES2105 `Object.values()`. Like so:

```
var array = Object.values(json);
```

Read more about `Object.values()` on the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

---

And here's your working demo:

```js
var json = {
 "imageList": [
  {
    "image_1": "/animals/1",
    "image_2": "/animals/2",
    "image_3": "/animals/3",
    "image_4": "/animals/4",
    "image_5": "/animals/5",
    "image_6": "/cats/1",
    "image_7": "/cats/2",
    "image_8": "/cats/3",
    "image_9": "/cats/4",
    "image_10": "/cats/5",
    "image_11": "/cats/6",
   }
 ]
};

var arr = Object.values(json.imageList[0]);

$('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').each(function() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 + 1),
    img = $(this);
  img.attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100' + arr[num] + '');
  img.attr('data-block', num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ir_game_container">
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_game_window_container">
        <div class="ir_image_holder">
            <img class="ir_img_src" src=" " data-block="" data-rewardpoints="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.. So, i can use $.get('/data/imagelist.json') method to get Json array outside the file which this method rite?